# Работа с объектами js

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
var length = $('.menute').css('margin-left'); 
alert (length);
```

Данный код работает. Пытаюсь кэшировать и сделать так:

```
var menute = $('.menute');
var length =  $(menute).css('margin-left');
alert(length);
```

Так уже не работает. И так:

```
var length = menute.css('margin-left');
alert (length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menute.css('margin-left','10px')
```

Comment: исправил вопрос, уже перепробовал все, то, что вы предлагали - так же.

Comment: тогда сделай так

    var length = menute.css('margin-left');

Comment: я написал, что так тоже не работает

Comment: должно работать

    var menute = $('.menute');
    var length =  menute.css('margin-left');
    alert (length);

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});` не хватало

Comment: @Afimida Pffff. Закройте вопрос тогда уж или выберите ответ.